# How to make drilldown chart with Yii 2.0 from database

Tags: php, web, charts, yii2

I want to make drilldown chart. But when I click the chart, the drilldown doesnt work. Here is the picture

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhuIz.png)

Here is the code

the view code (index.php)

```
<?php $this->registerJs("
$(function () {
    $('#my-chart3').highcharts({
        chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fakultas'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: $tahun2
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'FAPERTA',
            data: $data_A,
            drilldown: 'data A1','data A2','data A3','data A4','data A5'

        }, 

        {
            name: 'FKH',
            data: $data_B
        },
        {
            name: 'FPIK',
            data: $data_C
        },
        {
            name: 'FAPET',
            data: $data_D
        },
        {
            name: 'FAHUTAN',
            data: $data_E
        },
        {
            name: 'FATETA',
            data: $data_F
        },
        {
            name: 'FMIPA',
            data: $data_G
        },
        {
            name: 'FEM',
            data: $data_H
        },
        {
            name: 'FEMA',
            data: $data_I
        },
        {
            name: 'DIPLOMA',
            data: $data_J
        }],

        drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'data A1',
            id: 'data A1',
            data: [$data_A1]
        },
        {
            name: 'data A2',
            id: 'data A2',
            data: $data_A2
        },
        {
            name: 'data A3',
            id: 'data A3',
            data: $data_A3
        },
        {
            name: 'data A4',
            id: 'data A4',
            data: $data_A4
        },
        {
            name: 'data A5',
            id: 'data A5',
            data: $data_A5
        }
        ]
}

});
});
")?>
```

this is the controller code

```
$masuk2= S2view::find();
        $awal2= $masuk2->orderBy('TahunMasuk ASC')->one()->TahunMasuk;
        $akhir2= $masuk2->orderBy('TahunMasuk DESC')->one()->TahunMasuk;

        $arr_A = [];
        $arr_B = [];
        $arr_C = [];
        $arr_D = [];
        $arr_E = [];
        $arr_F = [];
        $arr_G = [];
        $arr_H = [];
        $arr_I = [];
        $arr_J = [];
        $tahun2 = [];
        $arr_A1 = [];
        $arr_A2 = [];
        $arr_A3 = [];
        $arr_A4 = [];
        $arr_A5 = [];

        for($k=$awal2;$k<=$akhir2;$k++){

                if($awal2 == $k){
                    $jum_A = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'A'])->all());
                    $jum_B = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'B'])->all());
                    $jum_C = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'C'])->all());
                    $jum_D = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'D'])->all());
                    $jum_E = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'E'])->all());
                    $jum_F = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'F'])->all());
                    $jum_G = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'G'])->all());
                    $jum_H = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'H'])->all());
                    $jum_I = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'I'])->all());
                    $jum_J = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'J'])->all());
                    $jum_A1 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'A1'])->all());
                    $jum_A2 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'A2'])->all());
                    $jum_A3 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'A3'])->all());
                    $jum_A4 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'A4'])->all());
                    $jum_A5 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$awal2,'Fakultas'=>'A5'])->all());

                }elseif($k > $awal2 && $k <= $akhir2){
                    $jum_A = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'A'])->all());
                    $jum_B = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'B'])->all());
                    $jum_C = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'C'])->all());
                    $jum_D = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'D'])->all());
                    $jum_E = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'E'])->all());
                    $jum_F = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'F'])->all());
                    $jum_G = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'G'])->all());
                    $jum_H = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'H'])->all());
                    $jum_I = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'I'])->all());
                    $jum_J = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'J'])->all());
                    $jum_A1 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'A1'])->all());
                    $jum_A2 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'A2'])->all());
                    $jum_A3 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'A3'])->all());
                    $jum_A4 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'A4'])->all());
                    $jum_A5 = count($masuk2->where(['TahunMasuk'=>$k,'Fakultas'=>'A5'])->all());
                }
                array_push($arr_A,$jum_A);
                array_push($arr_B,$jum_B);
                array_push($arr_C,$jum_C);
                array_push($arr_D,$jum_D);
                array_push($arr_E,$jum_E);
                array_push($arr_F,$jum_F);
                array_push($arr_G,$jum_G);
                array_push($arr_H,$jum_H);
                array_push($arr_I,$jum_I);
                array_push($arr_J,$jum_J);
                array_push($tahun2,$k);
                array_push($arr_A1,$jum_A1);
                array_push($arr_A2,$jum_A2);
                array_push($arr_A3,$jum_A3);
                array_push($arr_A4,$jum_A4);
                array_push($arr_A5,$jum_A5);
                }


        $data['tahun2'] = json_encode($tahun2);
        $data['data_A'] = json_encode($arr_A);
        $data['data_B'] = json_encode($arr_B);
        $data['data_C'] = json_encode($arr_C);
        $data['data_D'] = json_encode($arr_D);
        $data['data_E'] = json_encode($arr_E);
        $data['data_F'] = json_encode($arr_F);
        $data['data_G'] = json_encode($arr_G);
        $data['data_H'] = json_encode($arr_H);
        $data['data_I'] = json_encode($arr_I);
        $data['data_J'] = json_encode($arr_J);
        $data['data_A1'] = json_encode($arr_A1);
        $data['data_A2'] = json_encode($arr_A2);
        $data['data_A3'] = json_encode($arr_A3);
        $data['data_A4'] = json_encode($arr_A4);
        $data['data_A5'] = json_encode($arr_A5);



        return $this->render('index',$data);
    }
```

but those codes result error.
The error code is

```
series: [
        {
            name: 'FAPERTA',
            data: $data_A,
            drilldown: 'data A1','data A2','data A3','data A4','data A5'

        },
```

Please help me to solve that problem. What may I do to solve that problem? It'd help me so much. Thankyou

Comment: Please provide more detailed error or exception that you encounter

Comment: @koceeng I've edited it. please help me to solve that problem

Comment: You can just use the composer to get the highchart widget [here](https://packagist.org/packages/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget) .
Is there any specific reason you don't use the composer?

Comment: @Nue I have used composer to get the highchart widget, but I dont know why my chart could be like that